# Unit testing: How do I mock the innerWidth property on the window object with Angular + Jasmine?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, angular8

I want to write a unit test which expects a variable to contain a specific value depending on the `innerWidth` of the window.

In my unit test, I use `window.innerWidth = 1000;`. However, I receive an error which says `Cannot assign to 'innerWidth' because it is a read-only property.`.

Code (home.component.spec.ts):

```
  xit('should order the cards in the appropriate order on desktop', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'reOrderCards');
    window.innerWidth = 1000;
  })
```

Is there any way to mock the `innerWidth` property?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this is possible. As a workaround, I've created another variable which stores the value of `innerWidth` so it can be unit tested properly.

```
public screenWidth: number;

ngOnInit() {
   this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth; // Get initial innerWidth so the variable is immediately defined for reOrderCards() to recognise
   this.reOrderCards();
}


  @HostListener('window:resize', [])
  onResize() {
    this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    this.reOrderCards();
  }

reOrderCards() {
if(this.screenWidth < 768) {
 // Do logic
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could try returning window.innerwidth from another method and mock that function to return different values as desired.

https://emailtoanees.medium.com/angular-unit-test-window-innerwidth-c523d2e64eaf

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for some solution to mock the innerWidth property. This is a good example https://emailtoanees.medium.com/angular-unit-test-window-innerwidth-c523d2e64eaf but was not exactly that i wanted.
So my solution was implement a WindowMock class with the property and modify it in any section.

```js
class WindowMock {
 private _innerWidth: number;
 constructor() {
   this._innerWidth = 0;
 }
 get innerWidth(): number {
   return this._innerWidth;
 }
 set innerWidth(value: number) {
   this._innerWidth = value;
 }
} 

describe('myServiceTest', ()=> {
let window: Window;
let myService: MyServcie;
beforeEach(() => {
   const windowMock: WindowMock = new WindowMock();
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     providers: [MyService, { provide: Window, useValue: windowMock }],
   });
   window= TestBed.inject(Window) as jasmine.SpyObj<Window>;
   myService= TestBed.inject(MyService);
 });
it('getInnerWith() method should return 1050', () => {
   spyOnProperty(window, 'innerWidth').and.returnValue(1050);
   expect(myService.getInnerWith()).toEqual(1050);
 });
it('getInnerWith() method should return 500', () => {
   spyOnProperty(window, 'innerWidth').and.returnValue(500);
   expect(myService.getInnerWith()).toEqual(500);
 });
})
```